# Where should my method(s) that connect to DynamoDB go?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, database, nosql, client

I'm a Java developer working on a new module for my app that connects to, inserts, and updates DynamoDB information. For a lot of our projects, I used an MVC design pattern with a service layer to abstract business logic and bridge the gap between my controllers and model/data access layer.

We normally use PostgreSQL with an ORM to interact with data.

I have all of my credentials and dependencies to connect to my DynamoDB database. I'm just not sure what the best practice is in terms of where to put this. I read AWS SDK suggests using the builder methods to connect, which I have, but I'm not familiar with the builder design pattern (that may not even be relevant).

My first inclination is to call this new DynamoDB connection class `DynamoDBClient`, but upon doing some searching I don't see anything about adding a client layer to a software tier. I could make a new package (`com.carella.anthony.clients`), but is that common practice?

Where should I put this? Or rather, how should I construct this into my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a new package `Infrastructure` that contains all the configurations and connections for all your database/caching/messaging systems.

```
Infrastructure
    \DynamoConnection.java
    \DynamoConfiguration.java
    \IDynamoConnection.java
    \IDynamoConfiguration.java
```

The credentials should be managed by a `DynamoConfiguration` class that reads from a configuration file.

The connection itself should be managed by a `DynamoConnection` class that accepts a `DynamoConfiguration` as a parameter and builds the connection during the object initialization.

```
public class DynamoConnection implements IDynamoConnection {

    private final AmazonDynamoDB connection;
    private final DynamoConfiguration config;

    public DynamoConnection(DynamoConfiguration config) {
        this.config = config;
        this.connection = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(this.config.region())
            .withCredentials(this.config.credentials())
            .withClientConfiguration(this.config.clientConfiguration())
            .build();
    }

    public AmazonDynamoDB connection() {
        return this.connection;
    }
}
```

It would look something like the code above.